# Need to add two div to same block - shopify noob

Tags: html, class, shopify, element, liquid

I am a shopify noob who is new to html and css.
[shipping and price](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axFUL.png)
This image shows what im talking about. Now i will show u the 2 div one is price other is the free shipping thing and its called product__tax caption rte

```
            {%- when 'price' -%}
              <div class="no-js-hidden" id="price-{{ section.id }}" role="status" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
                <b>{%- render 'price',
                  product: product,
                  use_variant: true,
                  show_badges: true,
                  price_class: 'price--large',                
                  -%}</b>
              </div>   
              {%- if cart.taxes_included or shop.shipping_policy.body != blank -%}
                <div class="">
                  {%- if shop.shipping_policy.body != blank -%}
                    {{ 'products.product.shipping_policy_html' | t: link: shop.shipping_policy.url }}
                  {%- endif -%}
                </div>
              {%- endif -%}
```

This is the html for the two classes. They print one after another and i need to put them on the same line to save space on my product page. I can edit css too if there is a solution using css.